# Suppose I have Origin (0, 0) and a point (10, -10) on a Cartesian plane (JavaScript), how would I calculate bearing from the "North"?

Tags: javascript, coordinates

Point (x1, y1) as in Cartesian Coordinates

The "Bearing" between:

- Origin (0, 0) and point (10, 0) is 90 degrees
- Origin (0, 0) and point (10, -10) is 135 degrees
- Origin (0, 0) and point (0, -10) is 180 degrees
  etc.

Help on this is much appreciated, thanks!

```js
// Converts from degrees to radians.
function toRadians(degrees) {
  return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
};

// Converts from radians to degrees.
function toDegrees(radians) {
  return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
}

function bearing(destLat, destLng) {
  // startLat, startLng
  startLat = toRadians(0);
  startLng = toRadians(0);
  destLat = toRadians(destLat);
  destLng = toRadians(destLng);

  y = Math.sin(destLng - startLng) * Math.cos(destLat);
  x = Math.cos(startLat) * Math.sin(destLat) -
    Math.sin(startLat) * Math.cos(destLat) * Math.cos(destLng - startLng);
  brng = Math.atan2(y, x);
  brng = toDegrees(brng);
  return ((brng + 360) % 360).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(bearing(1023, 1023)); // returns me 208.57 but is supposed to be 135 degrees
```

[image]

Comment: Are you having trouble with the math, or the code?

Comment: @takendarkk Hi Im having problems implementing it in Javascript code. I understand the math behind this.

Comment: In that case, you seem to need a JavaScript tutorial, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Then can you post the math formula you have and the code you already wrote for it? From there we might be able to see where the issue was in translation. As it stands this is just asking us to write all the code from scratch for you.

Comment: @Prune Hi thanks for the response :) Most of the tutorials are in terms of lat long and do not have any in terms of the Cartesian plane, that is why I am asking, thanks

Comment: @takendarkk Hello, my current code has been uploaded, please take a look gentlemen

Comment: If you understand the math, all you need is skill with the Javascript syntax, right?

Comment: Why are you converting lats and longs to radians? They are not angles.

Comment: @Prune Thanks for the input, it is function for MicroBit, so its in type script, i am trying to implement it in another way

Answer (score 1):

As StackOverthrow pointed out earlier, your conversion from a linear distance to radians is invalid.  Even more, most of your equations are incorrect: those are the equations to convert *spherical* coordinates to Cartesian -- which you then convert to polar.

You already *have* the Cartesian coordinates: they are your input `(x, y)` values.

I don't have JS on this machine, but here is a simple Python solution for the parts you keep of your current code:

```
import math

def bearing(y, x):
    dir = math.degrees(math.atan2(x, y))
    if dir < 0:
        dir += 360
    return dir

root3 = 3**(0.5)
test = [
    ( 1,  root3),
    (-1,  root3),
    (-1, -root3),
    ( 1, -root3),
    ]

for point in test:
    print(point[0],
          round(point[1], 2),
          round(bearing(*point),2)); # returns me 208.57 but is supposed to be 135 degrees
```

Output (columns aligned by hand-editing)

```
 1  1.73  60.0
-1  1.73 120.0
-1 -1.73 240.0
 1 -1.73 300.0
```